# React-native Icon not aligned at centre of the view

Tags: html, react-native

This is the code I've used to make an icon position in the centre of the circular view with a background color:

```
import EEIcon from "react-native-vector-icons/Entypo";
              <View
               style={{
                      backgroundColor: "#F2F2F2",
                      alignItems: "center",
                      justifyContent: "center",
                      height: 25,
                      width: 25,
                      borderRadius: 12.5
                    }}
                  >
                    <EEIcon
                      name="location-pin"
                      style={{ color: "#fff", fontSize: 15 }}
                    />
                  </View>
```

[image: This is how the icon looks like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give padding to icon from top and left ----

```
<EEIcon name="location-pin" style={{ color: "#fff", fontSize: 15, paddingTop:3, paddingLeft:2 }} />
```

Here is the working example
https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/icon-center

Answer (score 1):

In order for alignItem and justifyContent to work, display should be set to 'flex':

```
   style={{
          backgroundColor: "#F2F2F2",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
          height: 25,
          width: 25,
          borderRadius: 12.5,
          display:"flex"
    }}
```